# Multiple JSON arrays as reponses - AJAX & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a PHP script setup that echo's JSON responses depending on what the user has done (or not done as the case may be):

The responses look like this:

```
{"type":"error","response":"Script error, please reload the page and try again.
Code: [NAct]","title":"Exception","hide":false}
```

Each response is generated like this:

```
echo $form -> ajax_response('error', 'Script error, please reload the page and try again.<br>Code: [NAct]', 'Exception', false);
```

This is picked up by pNotify and displayed - lovely. (See below .done function for ajax request)

```
request.done(function(msg) {
    //validate json response
    if (!tryParseJSON(msg)) {
        document.write(msg);
    } else {
        var array = json_to_array(msg);
    }
    if (array['type'] !== 'none') {
        if (array['title'] !== null) {
            pushNotification(array['title'], array['response'], array['type'], array['hide']);
        } else {
            pushNotification(ucfirst(array['type']), array['response'], array['type'], array['hide']);
        }
    }
    ready_status();
});
```

**If** the response cannot be validated by `tryParseJSON()`; the reponse is written directly to the page for debugging.

The problem is when I `echo` multiple responses back like this:

```
{"type":"error","response":"Script error, please reload the page and try again.
Code: [NAct]","title":"Exception","hide":false}

{"type":"error","response":"Script error, please reload the page and try again.
Code: [NDat]","title":"Exception","hide":false}
```

`tryParseJSON()` sees it as mumbo jumbo and prints it to the page.

## Question

How do i pick up the above two lines as separate responses and parse them through my function and sub-sequentially to `pNotify` without combining them into a single JSON array?

## Solution

As pointed out this was over complicated. Instead I combined each response (PHP side) into a an array:

```
$res['json'][] = $form -> ajax_response('error', 'Script error, please reload the page and try again.<br>Code: [NAct]', 'Exception', false);
```

Then echo'ed it at the end of the script:

```
echo json_encode($res['json');
```

On client side, I used a for loop, sending them to pNotify in each iteration:

```
request.done(function(msg) {
    //validate json response
    if (!tryParseJSON(msg)) {
        document.write(msg);
    } else {
        var obj = json_to_array(msg);
    }
    for (var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
        if (obj[i]['type'] !== 'none') {
            if (obj[i]['title'] !== null) {
                pushNotification(obj[i]['title'], obj[i]['response'], obj[i]['type'], obj[i]['hide']);
            } else {
                pushNotification(ucfirst(obj[i]['type']), obj[i]['response'], obj[i]['type'], obj[i]['hide']);
            }
        }
    }
    ready_status();
});
```

Comment: And why wouldn't you just join them on the server to an array, instead of messing around with invalid JSON on the clientside ?

Comment: @adeneo why is this 'invalid JSON'? Because the system is setup to echo the response immediately, to change it all would be a headache.

Comment: It's invalid because it's echoing two JSON snippets in the same script, without being wrapped in an array etc. so it's not neccessarely valid JSON when you join two strings of JSON together. It would be easier to just change it to valid JSON on the serverside than trying to mess with the function that tries to parse it on the client.

Comment: ok, so i have looked at my php, it doesn't seem like the end of the world if i combined them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating so sperate JSON-Outputs merge it to one single output string.

For this just wrap your two arrays you are currently outputting separately in an array like so

```
$myOutput[0] = responseArray1;
$myOutput[1] = responseArray2;
echo json_encode($myOutput);
```

This way you will get a valid JSON-response. Everything else is just some dirty workaround and causes shivers to everyone who has to review your work.